# Multiple Variables in Deliver Response

Tags: php, json, web-services

I have stored in the `$results` an array and my code is this:

```
deliver_responce("success", "ticket found", $results[0]);
```

I want to deliver a response with all the elements of the `$results` array.

Thanks in advance!

Deliver Response Function

```
function deliver_responce($status, $status_message, $data) {



header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
$response ['status'] = $status;
$response['status_message'] = $status_message;
$response['data'] = $data;
$json_response = json_encode($response);
echo $json_response;
```

}

Comment: What does `deliver_responce` do?

Comment: Well you can't deliver multiple different HTTP responses in a single request. You can however return the entire results array instead of just entry[0]

Comment: ok! thank you, it works in that way! How can convert the $data into xml ?

Comment: I think the `header()` line should read `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` or, at most, `header("HTTP/1.1 200 $status_message");`. Otherwise you will confuse the code that consumes your API. The response code `200` is important, it tell the client code the request was successful. The response text `OK` is just a description, you can safely use your `$status_message` instead.

Comment: header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8")

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to deliver all the values from `$response`. I would implement the function `deliver_response()` like this:

```
function deliver_response($status, $message, array $data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 $status_message");
    $response = array(
        'status'         => $status,
        'status_message' => $status_message,
        'data'           => $data,
    );
    echo(json_encode($response));
}
```

You call it by:

```
deliver_response("success", "ticket found", $results);
```

The client of the API reads the response body (using whatever communication mechanism you want) into a variable `$body` then uses `json_decode($body, TRUE);` to get back the array you stored in `$response` and do whatever it wants with the data:

```
$body = file_get_contents('URL of the API here');
$response = json_decode($body, TRUE);

echo('Status: '.$response['status']."\n");
echo('Message: '.$response['status_message']."\n");
echo('Data: '); print_r($response['data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains multiple index , why you are passing single element $results[0]. try this `deliver_responce("success", "ticket found", $results);`